# how to load an image from a variable in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, requirejs

ok firstly i am adding to cart, the way i am doing it is passing the necessary data as a parameter to a function and then sending does data to an `asyncstorage`(including the image), on my cart page i get from that `asyncstorage` and display the name and the price of the items but displaying the image is a problem
here is how it looks in code:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.button}
     onPress={() =>
      add(
      'Furts Camera',
       require('../resources/Cameras.jpg'),
       '10,00.00',
      )
    }>
  <Text style={styles.cart}>Add To Cart</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

then the function looks like this:

```
  const addcart = async (n, p, pr) => {
    statenum = statenum + 1;
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify({y: statenum}));
      getcartnum();
      let items = await AsyncStorage.getItem('items');
      stateitems = JSON.parse(items);
      if (stateitems.name == '') {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'items',
          JSON.stringify({name: n, pic: p, price: pr}),
        );
      } else {
        newname = stateitems.name + '|' + n;
        newpic = stateitems.pic + '|' + p;
        newprice = stateitems.price + '|' + pr;
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'items',
          JSON.stringify({name: newname, pic: newpic, price: newprice}),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e + 'first error');
    }
  };
```

and this is how i display the info on the screen:

```
const getcartitems = async () => {
    let items = await AsyncStorage.getItem('items');
    stateitems = JSON.parse(items);
    cartitemsfunc(items);
    console.log('sjsjs' + cartitems);
  };
  getcartnum();
  const views = [];
try {
    let red = JSON.parse(cartitems);
    console.log('this is red' + red);
    let splitname = red.name.split('|');
    let splitpic = red.pic.split('|');
    let splitprice = red.price.split('|');
for (let i = 0; i < cartnumpass; i++) {
views.push(
 ...
Image source={splitpic[i]} style={styles.image} />
...
)
}
}catch(e)
{
console.log(e)
}
```

then in the return:

```
 <View style={styles.main}>
     {views}        
  </View>
```

if i alert `splitpic[i]` it shows 56 (that is when i pass `require('../resources/Cameras.jpg')` as a parameter)
if i pass just `'../resources/Cameras.jpg'` as a parameter it alerts the string but when it shows the error below:

[image]

i even tried doing it this way:`require({splitpic[i]})`
and got almost a similar error

anyone know what to do, thanks in advance

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to do a dynamic require which does not work. So the best way is to require beforehand and use it.

Lets say that your array is like this.

```
const splitpic=['imagessource1','imagesource2'];
```

you will have to change it to

```
const splitpic=[require('imagessource1'),require('imagesource2')];
```

And use it like below

```
<Image source={splitpic[i]} style={styles.image} />
```

**Update after change in your question**

You are trying to require and store inside async storage, for the above solution to work you can do like below. You will have to create an object with all your images first this will act like a module with all images.

```
const resources = {
  Camera :require('../resources/Cameras.jpg')
};

add(
      'Furts Camera',
       'Camera',
       '10,00.00',
      )
```

And after your retrieve, you can do like below. By using the map you can simply require the image.

```
const getcartitems = async () => {
    let items = await AsyncStorage.getItem('items');
    stateitems = JSON.parse(items).map(x=>{x.pic=resources[x.pic];return x;});
    cartitemsfunc(items);
    console.log('sjsjs' + cartitems);
  };
```

Comment: ok this works but, it seems like am not telling the full story, I'll edit the question

Comment: just copying and pasting the code flag this error, Error:TransformError pages\Cart.js: pages\Cart.js:Invalid call at line 60:require(x.pic)